# How to find a lost Ark Survival Evolved Tamed (Non Dead ) Dino?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I was on the beach with my best dino, he was set to neutral and to not follow, however I don't remember where I died. He's still alive but I can't find him. Any help?

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate, tell us *how* it's not.  To the casual observer, it seems like it's asking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "show my location on the map" on (probably just butchered the name)? If you do, you can go to the location it said that you died on the map.

Comment: This was a few days ago, so I don't think that would work..